# What http code to return in ListAPIView?

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

I have a simple view that lists Events in django-rest-framework:

```
class EventListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_position = self.request.query_params.get('position', '')
        if not user_position or not re.match(r'^-?\d+\.\d+,-?\d+\.\d+$', user_position):
            raise APIException('Position is absent or invalid')

        return Event.objects.filter(...)
```

For this view, I need to validate that the `position` parameter is present and well formed. If it's not, I want to return an appropriate HTTP error code.

As I do right now, in case of error, the API returns a 500 error code, which I think is bad.

Is there a more specific HTTP error code I should return? I think status code 400 might be appropriate, but how can I return that code explicitly in my view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above could work if you were raising the DRF's ValidationError. The DRF ValidationError causes the view to return a `HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST` status.

It might be the APIException that is causing the 500. If you want to use th APIException make sure it sub-classes the ValidationError from DRF.

Answer (score 0):

ListAPIView extends GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin

[listapiview](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview)

Take a look at the docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listmodelmixin you can override the list method and return the error code of your choosing. Link here for example http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#examples